# Rmarkdown stop generating after a paragraph

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

So my problem is that after a specific paragraph Rmarkdown doesn't generating the rest of the code and I don't know why. Note that if I delete that paragraph the program will render untill the next text paragraph and then do the same thing.

Here is a minimal markdown example with the problematic paragraph. The code block and text after the code block do not show up in the PDF.

````
---
title: "Proiect Regresie"
author: "Andrei Alexandru; grupa 322"
output: pdf_document
---

# Estimarea parametrilor

Considerăm modelul de regresie liniară simplă  $y=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x +\varepsilon$ (unde x venitul provenit din vanzarile in America de Nord iar
y venitul provenit din vanzarile la nivel mondial, $\varepsilon$ este repartizat normal de medie 0 și varianță sigma p\u atrat. Estimatorii parametrilor $\beta_{0}$ \c si $\beta_{1}$ ob\c tinu\c ti prin metoda celor mai mici pătrate sunt calcula\c ti \^in R. 

```{r}
mtcars
```

Some more text.
````

Comment: Hi Hector. This is a lot of text, and the lack of formatting makes it difficult to digest. Can you please try and reduce your markdown text to the bit that causes the problem. One way to do that would be for you to iteratively delete text from the beginning and end until you get the *minimal* block of text that causes the issue. At this point, it's not even clear to me *which* part in the markdown text is causing you grief.

Comment: PS. Just a piece of advice: Adding "This is urgent" rarely helps with getting an answer quicker. However: Providing minimal data and code to reproduce the issue *may* help with getting an answer quicker :-)

Comment: the main issue is that after this paragraph "Considerăm modelul de regresie liniară simplă $y=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x +\varepsilon$ (unde x venitul provenit din vanzarile in America de Nord iar y venitul provenit din vanzarile la nivel mondial, $\varepsilon$ este repartizat normal de medie 0 și varianță sigma p\u atrat. Estimatorii parametrilor $\beta_{0}$ \c si $\beta_{1}$ ob\c tinu\c ti prin metoda celor mai mici pătrate sunt calcula\c ti \^in R" the rest of the code will not show in the ouput

Comment: maybe is the problem with the code after that paragraph...idk...I was thinking all day about it and didn't find the issue. I had the same problem at the beggining of the code butt somehow (idk how) i fixed it...so yeah...
My teacher said that I need to read more carefully how to make rmarkdown files... I read it...and still didn't find the issue

Comment: Hector, a good way to figure out what the problem is (and to help us help you) is to reduce the size of your file as much as possible, as Maurits suggested. What happens if you remove everything that follows the last paragraph above? Does that still give you an error? If not, start adding small chunks of text and code back in until it fails again. Then you'll have a much better idea where the problem is. You may have to do the same thing with the beginning of your document but make sure the R code remains valid.

Comment: If it's only the last paragraph, then do you really need to include all the other stuff in your post? Is it relevant here? Also, please note that the code you give is not reproducible, because we don't have access to `"~/video_games/vgsales.xlsx"`. So this means that we can't actually reproduce the issue you're describing. It would help if you reduce your example to a *minimal* example, such that when we copy&paste the code into a markdown document, we can reproduce what you're describing.

Comment: @HectorGuy To give you an idea of what constitutes a minimal & reproducible example, I've edited your post to include a minimal reprex. If I copy & paste this into an empty markdown document, I can confirm that the code block (and anything that comes after it) does not get rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the special characters (`\c`, etc.) are causing this problem. You need to specify the language using `babel`. Since it is a LaTeX package, you need to put it in `header-includes` in YAML.

Here are two examples of the changes you need to do:

- `\c si` needs to be rewritten `\c{s}i`
- `ob\c tinu\c ti` needs to be rewritten `ob\c{t}inu\c{t}i`

However, I can't figure out why using `\^i` or `\^{i}` does not work.

Full example:

````
---
title: "Proiect Regresie"
author: "Andrei Alexandru; grupa 322"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[romanian]{babel}
---

# Estimarea parametrilor

Considerăm modelul de regresie liniară simplă  $y=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x +\varepsilon$ (unde x venitul provenit din vanzarile in America de Nord iar
y venitul provenit din vanzarile la nivel mondial, $\varepsilon$ este repartizat normal de medie 0 și varianță sigma p\u{a}trat. Estimatorii parametrilor $\beta_{0}$ \c{s}i $\beta_{1}$ ob\c{t}inu\c{t}i prin metoda celor mai mici pătrate sunt calcula\c{t}i \^{i}n R. 

```{r}
mtcars
```

Some more text.
````